# base64 in PHP Otp Library

Tags: php, base64, one-time-password

I trying to make some simple library for encrypting files in PHP with OTP method. My problem is that some chars in decrypted code are different than original. I worked on it almost one week but without result. Is there problem with base64 chars or with encoding/decoding mechanism ?

Many thanks for the answers.

```
final class Otp
{

    private static $charSet = array('+','/','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L',
    'M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r',
    's','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');

    public static function encryptFile($originalFilePath, $encryptedFilePath, $keyFilePath)
    {

        if(!self::existsFile($keyFilePath) || !self::existsFile($encryptedFilePath)) {

            if($originalFileData = self::existsFile($originalFilePath)) {

                $originalFileBase64Data = base64_encode($originalFileData);
                $originalFileBase64DataLength = strlen($originalFileBase64Data) - 1;
                $originalFileBase64DataArray = str_split($originalFileBase64Data);

                $encryptedData = NULL;
                $encryptedDataKey = NULL;
                for ($i = 0; $i <= $originalFileBase64DataLength; $i++) {

                    $randKey = rand(0, sizeOf(self::$charSet) - 1);
                    $arrayKey = array_search($originalFileBase64DataArray[$i], self::$charSet);

                    if($randKey > $arrayKey) {
                        $str = '-' . ($randKey - $arrayKey);
                    } elseif($randKey < $arrayKey) {
                        $str = ($randKey + $arrayKey);
                    } else {
                        $str = $randKey;
                    }

                    $encryptedData .= self::$charSet[$randKey];
                    $encryptedDataKey .= $str. ';';

                }

                $encryptedDataString = $encryptedData;
                $encryptedDataKeyString = $encryptedDataKey;

                if(!self::existsFile($keyFilePath)) {
                    file_put_contents($keyFilePath, $encryptedDataKeyString);
                }

                if(!self::existsFile($encryptedFilePath)) {
                    file_put_contents($encryptedFilePath, $encryptedDataString);
                }

                return 'OK';

            } else {
                return 'Source file not exists';
            }

        } else {
            return 'Encrypted data already exists';
        }
    }

    public static function decryptFile($encryptedFilePath, $keyFilePath, $decryptedFilePath)
    {

        $keyFileData = self::existsFile($keyFilePath);
        $encryptedFileData = self::existsFile($encryptedFilePath);
        $encryptedFileDataLength = strlen($encryptedFileData) - 1;

        if($encryptedFileData && $keyFileData) {

            $encryptedFileDataArray = str_split($encryptedFileData);
            $keyFileDataArray = explode(';', $keyFileData);

            $decryptedData = NULL;
            for ($i = 0; $i <= $encryptedFileDataLength; $i++) {

                $poziciaaktualneho = array_search($encryptedFileDataArray[$i], self::$charSet);
                $poziciasifrovana = $keyFileDataArray[$i];
                if($poziciasifrovana < 0) {
                    $move = $poziciasifrovana + $poziciaaktualneho;
                } elseif($poziciasifrovana > 0) {
                    $move = $poziciasifrovana - $poziciaaktualneho;
                } else {
                    $move = '0';
                }
                $decryptedData .= self::$charSet[$move];

            }

            if(!self::existsFile($decryptedFilePath)) {
                file_put_contents($decryptedFilePath, base64_decode($decryptedData));
                return 'OK';
            } else {
                return 'Decrypted data already exists';
            }

        }

    }

    private static function existsFile($filePath)
    {
        $fileData = @file_get_contents($filePath);
        if($fileData) {
            return $fileData;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

}


$originalFilePath = 'original.jpg';
$keyFilePath = 'Otp_Key_' . $originalFilePath;
$encryptedFilePath = 'Otp_Data_' . $originalFilePath;
$decryptedFilePath = 'Otp_Decrypted_' . $originalFilePath;

echo Otp::encryptFile($originalFilePath, $encryptedFilePath, $keyFilePath);
echo Otp::decryptFile($encryptedFilePath, $keyFilePath, $decryptedFilePath);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you show your current code and where you are experiencing problems, so we can figure out what your problem is?

Comment: already here. sorry I am new here.

Comment: By OTP do you mean one-time-password?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own

Comment: One Time Pad https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad

Comment: @tomdawayhet Why are you decreasing the data length by 1 on line 17?

Comment: because array is from 0 not from 1. is it problem you think ?

Comment: but what I don´t understand is there are just a few different chars. the file looks like picture after decrypting but there are errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be only happening when `$poziciaaktualneho` is equal to `$poziciasifrovana` and so by adding another if statement on line 78 to check for this and instead set `$move` equal to `$poziciasifrovana` I was able to fix the problem. The below script should work:

```
final class Otp
{

    private static $charSet = array('+','/','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L',
    'M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r',
    's','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');

    public static function encryptFile($originalFilePath, $encryptedFilePath, $keyFilePath)
    {

        if(!self::existsFile($keyFilePath) || !self::existsFile($encryptedFilePath)) {

            if($originalFileData = self::existsFile($originalFilePath)) {

                $originalFileBase64Data = base64_encode($originalFileData);
                $originalFileBase64DataLength = strlen($originalFileBase64Data) - 1;
                $originalFileBase64DataArray = str_split($originalFileBase64Data);

                $encryptedData = NULL;
                $encryptedDataKey = NULL;
                for ($i = 0; $i <= $originalFileBase64DataLength; $i++) {

                    $randKey = rand(0, sizeOf(self::$charSet) - 1);
                    $arrayKey = array_search($originalFileBase64DataArray[$i], self::$charSet);

                    if($randKey > $arrayKey) {
                        $str = '-' . ($randKey - $arrayKey);
                    } elseif($randKey < $arrayKey) {
                        $str = ($randKey + $arrayKey);
                    } else {
                        $str = $randKey;
                    }

                    $encryptedData .= self::$charSet[$randKey];
                    $encryptedDataKey .= $str. ';';

                }

                $encryptedDataString = $encryptedData;
                $encryptedDataKeyString = $encryptedDataKey;

                if(!self::existsFile($keyFilePath)) {
                    file_put_contents($keyFilePath, $encryptedDataKeyString);
                }

                if(!self::existsFile($encryptedFilePath)) {
                    file_put_contents($encryptedFilePath, $encryptedDataString);
                }

                return 'OK';

            } else {
                return 'Source file not exists';
            }

        } else {
            return 'Encrypted data already exists';
        }
    }

    public static function decryptFile($encryptedFilePath, $keyFilePath, $decryptedFilePath)
    {

        $keyFileData = self::existsFile($keyFilePath);
        $encryptedFileData = self::existsFile($encryptedFilePath);
        $encryptedFileDataLength = strlen($encryptedFileData) - 1;

        if($encryptedFileData && $keyFileData) {

            $encryptedFileDataArray = str_split($encryptedFileData);
            $keyFileDataArray = explode(';', $keyFileData);

            $decryptedData = NULL;
            for ($i = 0; $i <= $encryptedFileDataLength; $i++) {

                $poziciaaktualneho = array_search($encryptedFileDataArray[$i], self::$charSet);
                $poziciasifrovana = $keyFileDataArray[$i];
                if ($poziciasifrovana == $poziciaaktualneho) {
                    $move = $poziciasifrovana;
                } elseif($poziciasifrovana < 0) {
                    $move = $poziciasifrovana + $poziciaaktualneho;
                } elseif($poziciasifrovana > 0) {
                    $move = $poziciasifrovana - $poziciaaktualneho;
                } else {
                    $move = '0';
                }
                $decryptedData .= self::$charSet[$move];

            }

            if(!self::existsFile($decryptedFilePath)) {
                file_put_contents($decryptedFilePath, base64_decode($decryptedData));
                return 'OK';
            } else {
                return 'Decrypted data already exists';
            }

        }

    }

    private static function existsFile($filePath)
    {
        $fileData = @file_get_contents($filePath);
        if($fileData) {
            return $fileData;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

}


$originalFilePath = 'original.jpg';
$keyFilePath = 'Otp_Key_' . $originalFilePath;
$encryptedFilePath = 'Otp_Data_' . $originalFilePath;
$decryptedFilePath = 'Otp_Decrypted_' . $originalFilePath;

echo Otp::encryptFile($originalFilePath, $encryptedFilePath, $keyFilePath);
echo Otp::decryptFile($encryptedFilePath, $keyFilePath, $decryptedFilePath);
```

> **Warning:** I would not recommend using my solution in an enterprise setting if at all since I do not know why this fixes your script or what was
>   originally wrong with it and it is most likely not air tight.

Comment: many many thanks. it is great. I testing it now and it looks perfect :)